# UseState is not updating inside await method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

What my code is trying to do is get an array of objects by doing multiple get requests. I am then pushing the **response.data** to the **setPokemonTeam** variable and it is not working. Everytime I log the array in console it appears empty.

```
const [pokemonTeam, setPokemonTeam] = useState([]);

const generatePokemon = async () => {
    setPokemonTeam([]);
    const pokemonIDs = [];

    do {
      const randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 121);

      if (!pokemonIDs.includes(randomID)) {
        pokemonIDs.push(randomID);
      }
    } while (pokemonIDs.length < 6); //max 6 pokemon only
    let promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pokemonIDs.length; i++) {
      promises.push(
        await axios
          .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIDs[i]}/`)
          .then((res) => {
            setPokemonTeam([...pokemonTeam, res.data]);
            console.log(res.data);
            console.log(pokemonTeam);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          })
      );
    }
    Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(pokemonTeam);
  };
```

my console is getting the correct data but it is not updating the **pokemonTeam** array.

[This is what my console looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEMe9.png)

[This is the code with each line included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUBVV.png)

Comment: you have a endless "loop". Once the program flows into the function, the promises are executed. When any completes, the state is updated, but that triggers another function run and another bunch of promises will start. You should use a useEffect to create and start the promises. The argument should be something will never change, like an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `useEffect(()=>console.log(pokemonTeams), [pokemonTeams])` before this function.

Also, have a look at [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and [UseEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is helpful for you.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [pokemonTeam, setPokemonTeam] = useState([])
  let pokemonIDs = []
  do {
    const randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 121)
    if (!pokemonIDs.includes(randomID)) {
      pokemonIDs.push(randomID)
    }
  } while (pokemonIDs.length < 6)

  useEffect(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < pokemonIDs.length; i++) {
      axios
        .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIDs[i]}`)
        .then((res) => {
          setPokemonTeam((prev) => [...prev, res.data])
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
  }, [])
  console.log(pokemonTeam)
  return 'Hello'
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of pokemonTeam is "[]" line 1 (set in useState):

```
const [pokemonTeam, setPokemonTeam] = useState([]);
```

You need to remove the line 3

```
setPokemonTeam([]);
```

To avoid reloading your component before the asynchronous request is finished executing